# Encrypted boot drops to shell, how to set LVM crypttab consistently? 'ALERT! {logical volume path} does not exist'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, encryption, luks

I used Luks to encrypt my whole hard drive, and created that `sda` drive as a physical volume. Under that volume, I create a volume group `vg00` with my 3 logical volumes

`lv00_root`, `lv01_home`, and `lv02_swap`
Here is my logical volumes, contained in the volume group `vg00` on physical volume `/dev/sda`

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo lvdisplay /dev/vg00
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/lv00_root
  LV Name                lv00_root
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                9bzRlY-LWT3-YBV5-yK9U-s3yT-n8MR-B5HjAP
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xubuntu, 2015-08-28 05:11:15 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                12.00 GiB
  Current LE             3072
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/lv01_home
  LV Name                lv01_home
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                B9Ykg2-65Aq-fOS2-1T9I-msfW-OlLf-yMDJT5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xubuntu, 2015-08-28 05:11:29 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                15.00 GiB
  Current LE             3840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/lv02_swap
  LV Name                lv02_swap
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                HHiMFa-D9fi-RH6B-ITN6-olQW-Fx0A-FSSzsY
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xubuntu, 2015-08-28 05:11:41 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:3
```

My `fstab` is as follows(note I already tried putting /dev/sda UUID as an entry, now commented):

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=d6055580-65af-4ef0-aba5-dfcecaa0c82f none luks defaults 0 1
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv00_root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=05b8b1aa-4067-4938-ad02-72c3d7fb7331 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01_home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv02_swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

My `/etc/crypttab` is as follows:

```
roothd UUID=d6055580-65af-4ef0-aba5-dfcecaa0c82f none luks
```

At the bootloader unlock screen, I would like to input my one existing passphrase for `/dev/sda` drive and unlock the volume group `vg00` which contains the all logical volumes.

I did run `update-initramfs -u` after any change to the `fstab` or `crypttab`

When I boot, after the grub screen I am dropped to the Ubuntu shell with: `ALERT! /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00_root does not exist` .

I have suspicion that it is a problem with grub due to grub.cfg having its linux `initramfs` generated image set to the path of `/dev/mapper/vg00-lv00_root`. I obviously need to decrypt `/dev/sda` parent physical volume before grub could access this.

FYI I roughly followed [this](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu) and [this](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/831121-how-to-full-encrypt-your-linux-system-with-lvm-on-luks) tutorial

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am now sure that my initramfs is on a LVM (vg00-lv00_root) inside my LUKS container. It is available only after the container is decrypted and the volume group assembled. This is my problem but I am not sure how to fix it.